# List comments received by every posts of an specific author

Tags: comments

The wordpress built-in **get_comments()** can easily list out comments base on post type, post meta, post id or comment author id. But I would like to bring them togather, list out recent **received** comments from posts of specific author.

My current way can only simply list all comments out:

```
    <?php
            $store_ID = $store_user->ID;
            $args = array(
                'status' => 'approve',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
                'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'rating',
                                'value'   => array(''),
                                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
                            ) 
                )
            );
            $comments = get_comments($args);
            if ( count( $comments ) == 0 ) {
                        echo '<span colspan="5">None message here</span>';
            } else {foreach ( $comments as $single_comment ) {
                        echo 'loop content';
            }
    ?>
```

So I am looking for the part to specify the loop stay inside posts of sepcific author. May be some sql skills are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can do that by nested query.

To get all comments of posts by a user, you should think about getting all post of that user first, then get the comments of that post.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'author' => AUTHOR_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 500, //Don't use -1 here
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
            $nested_args = array(
                'post_id' => get_the_ID()
            );
            $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
            $comments = $comments_query->query( $nested_args );
            if ( $comments ) {
                foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
                    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
                }
            }
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: That's the thing I want to achieve, gonna need some modification to make it run, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional parameter to your query to get only those for a specific author by id or name

```
 $args = array(
            'status' => 'approve',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
            'author' => 12,
            'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'rating',
                            'value'   => array(''),
                            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
                        ) 
            )
        );
```

Source : [WP query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters)

Show Posts for one Author

Display posts by author, using author id:

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => 123 ) );
Display posts by author, using author 'user_nicename':

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author_name' => 'rami' ) );

Comment: umm, kinda misunderstanding. This is getting the comment author, not fit this case. Thank you for the helping anyway!